# Breeze Entity defaultResourceName is undefined for sub-types when using inheritance

Tags: breeze

I have a Breeze Web API with a Vehicles, Cars, and Buses. Car and Bus types inherit from Vehicle type in a table per hierarchy database structure.

According to the Breeze docs one should be able to make the same query to call either the local cache (with executeQueryLocally) or the remote service (with executeQuery).

This does not work in the inheritance scenario for Buses and Cars because these types have their defaultResourceName = undefined. But it is odd that a call to the remote service works but not to the local cache. Code explains better:

```
    var EntityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery;
    var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('../../breeze/breeze');

    var getRemoteCars = function() {
        var query = EntityQuery.from('Cars');
        return manager.executeQuery(query)
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);
    };
    function querySucceeded(data) { console.log('Retrieved Cars from remote data source'); }
    function queryFailed(data) { console.log('Failed to retrieve Cars from remote data source'); }

    var getLocalCars = function () {
        console.log("getLocals called");  

        var newQuery = new EntityQuery('Cars');
        var cars = manager.executeQueryLocally(newQuery);
        if (cars) console.log("retrieved some cars from local cache");
        else console.log("no cars retrieved from local cache");
    };

    getRemoteCars().then(getLocalCars);
```

This code outputs:

```
Retrieved Cars from remote data source WebApiTest.html:26

getLocals called

Q] Unhandled rejection reasons (should be empty): []
```

The relevant error message is hidden by a Q.js error (which is a nuisance). Breeze.js threw an error that didn't make it to the Browser:

```
Cannot find an entityType for either entityTypeName: 'undefined' or resourceName: 'Cars'
```

It turns out the sub-types (Car and Bus) have defaultResourceName = undefined.

So I can fix the problem by adding:

```
manager.metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName("Cars", "Car");
manager.metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName("Buses", "Bus");
```

But that doesn't explain why the remote call worked.

So, firstly is this a bug that will be fixed and secondly, why does the remote call work when the local one does not?

EDIT 24 May 15:15 - More interesting behavior...

The above call to setEntityTypeForResourceName() must occur after the metadata has been retrieved from the server. But if you want to configure the metadataStore before this, you can use the fully qualified name like this:

```
manager.metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName("Cars", "Car:#VerySimpleVehicleModel.Models");
manager.metadataStore.setEntityTypeForResourceName("Buses", "Bus:#VerySimpleVehicleModel.Models");
```

Interestingly, with this solution the defaultResourceName for Car and Bus types remain undefined, but the local call works. Strange, no??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We were able to reproduce the problem and it does appear to be a bug. 
We are working on the fix.

Comment: After further investigation, we determined that this is not a bug. 
What happens is that EF only provides the resource name for the top of the hierarchy. So when you are querying from the datasource, data is coming (vehicles), but we don't really know whether it's cars or trucks.
Now, when querying locally, you must know exactly what type you are retrieving. Because of that you must specify the resource name for the type as you did. 
Another option would be creating a query as

var newQuery = new EntityQuery('Cars').toType("Car");